# How to recompile examples using Spark project's sources?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to java / scala and coming from python i don't know the compile phases... 
I  changed a scala example given with spark, but when I re-execute it, the changes are note taken into account. I guess it is because I am used not to compile my scripts :-/

What are the commands to compile a scala script ?
Namely : ~/spark/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/FlumePollingEventCount.scala

```
scalac /Users/romain/spark/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/FlumePollingEventCount2.scala
    /Users/romain/spark/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/FlumePollingEventCount2.scala:21: 

error: object SparkConf is not a member of package org.apache.spark
    import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
           ^
```

Comment: scalac finename.scala then scala CLASS_WITHMAIN_METHOD
there should be some tool like sbt or mvn

Answer (score 0):

According to [Running Build Targets For Individual Projects](http://spark.apache.org/developer-tools.html#individual-tests):

```
$ # sbt
$ build/sbt package
$ # Maven
$ build/mvn package -DskipTests -pl assembly
```

In your case it'd be `build/sbt examples:package`.

You may want to read up [Building Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-spark) to learn the build process in Spark.